# firebase data messages wake the app by default is not working in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have develope app with firebase notification. I know already some questions are asked on stackoverflow like:
**how to handle notification when app in background in Firebase.**

But my question is

> When my app is not running that time 'notification is received' but i am
>   not clicking/tapping on notification just open my application that time i want
>   update notification data but data is not updated. It is updated only when app is running.

In IOS **content_available:true** property is working. It says 
"On iOS, use this field to represent content-available in the APNs payload. 
When a notification or message is sent and this is set to true, 
an inactive client app is awoken. 
On Android, data messages wake the app by default. 
On Chrome, currently not supported."

*But data messages wake the app by default is not working.*

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks